# Iterating Over Dictionary Key Values Corresponding to List in Python

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, loops

Working in Python 2.7. I have a dictionary with team names as the keys and the amount of runs scored and allowed for each team as the value list:

```
NL_East = {'Phillies': [645, 469], 'Braves': [599, 548], 'Mets': [653, 672]}
```

I would like to be able to feed the dictionary into a function and iterate over each team (the keys).

Here's the code I'm using. Right now, I can only go team by team. How would I iterate over each team and print the expected win_percentage for each team?

```
def Pythag(league):
    runs_scored = float(league['Phillies'][0])
    runs_allowed = float(league['Phillies'][1])
    win_percentage = round((runs_scored**2)/((runs_scored**2)+(runs_allowed**2))*1000)
    print win_percentage
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You have several options for iterating over a dictionary.

If you iterate over the dictionary itself (`for team in league`), you will be iterating over the keys of the dictionary.  When looping with a for loop, the behavior will be the same whether you loop over the dict (`league`) itself, or [`league.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys):

```
for team in league.keys():
    runs_scored, runs_allowed = map(float, league[team])
```

You can also iterate over both the keys and the values at once by iterating over `league.items()`:

```
for team, runs in league.items():
    runs_scored, runs_allowed = map(float, runs)
```

You can even perform your tuple unpacking while iterating:

```
for team, (runs_scored, runs_allowed) in league.items():
    runs_scored = float(runs_scored)
    runs_allowed = float(runs_allowed)
```

Comment: dict.iteritems() was removed since Python3. You should use dict.items() instead

Comment: dict.iterkeys() was also removed in Python 3. You should use dict.keys() instead

Comment: dict.itervalues() was also removed in Python  3. You should use dict.values() instead

Comment: What about checking if a key available in a dict on if statement ? is it also the same?

Answer (score 11):

You can very easily iterate over dictionaries, too:

```
for team, scores in NL_East.iteritems():
    runs_scored = float(scores[0])
    runs_allowed = float(scores[1])
    win_percentage = round((runs_scored**2)/((runs_scored**2)+(runs_allowed**2))*1000)
    print '%s: %.1f%%' % (team, win_percentage)
```

Comment: @BurtonGuster: Whenever you think an answer worthy, please upvote (click the "up" button on the left side of the post)! That way you're helping the community, too!

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries have a built in function called `iterkeys()`.

Try:

```
for team in league.iterkeys():
    runs_scored = float(league[team][0])
    runs_allowed = float(league[team][1])
    win_percentage = round((runs_scored**2)/((runs_scored**2)+(runs_allowed**2))*1000)
    print win_percentage
```

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary objects allow you to iterate over their items. Also, with pattern matching and the division from `__future__` you can do simplify things a bit.

Finally, you can separate your logic from your printing to make things a bit easier to refactor/debug later.

```
from __future__ import division

def Pythag(league):
    def win_percentages():
        for team, (runs_scored, runs_allowed) in league.iteritems():
            win_percentage = round((runs_scored**2) / ((runs_scored**2)+(runs_allowed**2))*1000)
            yield win_percentage

    for win_percentage in win_percentages():
        print win_percentage
```

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension can shorten things...

```
win_percentages = [m**2.0 / (m**2.0 + n**2.0) * 100 for m, n in [a[i] for i in NL_East]]
```