# Parsing input from a json file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am new to python and looking for a help, I have a json file (input.json) which I am planning to use as an input file to my python (version 2.7.8) script.

```
{
  "esxIP": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
  "esxUser": "username",
  "esxPass": "password",
  "vm": {
    "vm1": [
      {
        "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "user": "username",
        "pass": "password"
      },
      {
        "device": "naa.axxxxxx1",
        "vmfsType": "vmfs5",
        "diskType": "thin"
      },
      {
        "device": "naa.axxxxxx2",
        "vmfsType": "vmfs6",
        "diskType": "thick"
      }
    ],
    "vm2": [
      {
        "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "user": "username",
        "pass": "password"
      },
      {
        "device": "naa.bxxxxxx1",
        "vmfsType": "vmfs5",
        "diskType": "thin"
      },
      {
        "device": "naa.bxxxxxx2",
        "vmfsType": "vmfs6",
        "diskType": "thick"
      }
    ],
    "vm3": [
      {
        "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
        "user": "username",
        "pass": "password"
      },
      {
        "device": "naa.cxxxxxx1",
        "vmfsType": "vmfs5",
        "diskType": "thin"
      },
      {
        "device": "naa.cxxxxxx2",
        "vmfsType": "vmfs6",
        "diskType": "thick"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With the below python code, I am able to get the values for a particular key when the key is known to me. e.g.

```
import json

with open('input.json') as f:
    jInput = json.load(f)
print jInput["vm"]["vm1"][1]["vmfsType"]
```

Here i am providing VM name as "vm1" in last print statement, which is printing vmfsType value for first device :

```
vmfs5
```

So here is my query:

1. In my case I can't hardcode VM name e.g. vm1, vm2 etc. because it not static. This input can be changed by each and every time, even sometimes there could be 2 vm's and sometimes there could be 4 vm's. So in code how can I get the VM name one by one and run specific commands with it's associated keys e.g.

   "vm1": [
     {
       "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
       "user": "username",
       "pass": "password"
     },
     {
       "device": "naa.axxxxxx1",
       "vmfsType": "vmfs5",
       "diskType": "thin"
     },
     {
       "device": "naa.axxxxxx2",
       "vmfsType": "vmfs6",
       "diskType": "thick"
     }
   ],
2. Same way their will be multiple devices for each VM but having same key name, how we can take them one by one and run command with it for particular VM.

Any help is appreciated here.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating Over Dictionary Key Values Corresponding to List in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409078/iterating-over-dictionary-key-values-corresponding-to-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
for vm_name, vm_data in jInput["vm"].items():
    print("workon on vm {}".format(vm_name)
    # cnx is the {"ip": ... etc} dict (first object in the list). 
    # devices is the list of {"device": ....} dicts
    cnx, devices = vm_data[0], vm_data[1:]
    for device in devices:
        do_something_with(cnx, device)
```

Iterating over a sequence is done with the `for` loop - `for item in sequence: use(item)` - where `item` will be assigned the first, then second, then third etc items from the sequence. For lists, this is quite straightforward. For dicts (which are sequences too), the default is to iterate on the keys, but you can have both keys and values using `dict.items()`, in which case you get, for each iteration, a `(key, value)` tuple. You can then use unpacking to assing each to a distinct iteration variable (ie `for key, value in dict.items(): ...`).

If you expect to do anything serious with Python you really need to learn how to iterate over different sequence types and how to use dicts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, since your `vm`s will be a pattern, I would use a simple regex to match key pattern -

```
import re
vm_pattern = r"^vm\d+"

for k, v in x["vm"]:
    if re.match(ptrn, k):
        # this will match patterns like vm1, vm12 etc
```

Now to access `device` for a vm, continue the above loop like so -

```
# continuing the above code
for dictionary in v[0]:
    try:
        device = dictionary['device']
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use the keys from jInput["vm"] to dinamically get the vm names:

   ```
   with open('test.json') as f:
       jInput = json.load(f)

   for k in (jInput["vm"].keys()):
       print k, " /", jInput["vm"][k][1]["vmfsType"]
   ```
2. instead of having:

   ```
   "vm3": [
       {
           "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
           "user": "username",
           "pass": "password"
       },
       {
           "device": "naa.cxxxxxx1",
           "vmfsType": "vmfs5",
           "diskType": "thin"
       },
       {
           "device": "naa.cxxxxxx2",
           "vmfsType": "vmfs6",
           "diskType": "thick"
       }
   ]
   ```

Consider having:

```
    "vm3": [
        {
            "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
            "user": "username",
            "pass": "password"
        },
        {
            "devices": {
                "device1": {
                    "id": "naa.cxxxxxx1",
                    "vmfsType": "vmfs5",
                    "diskType": "thin"
                },
                "device2": {
                    "id": "naa.cxxxxxx2",
                    "vmfsType": "vmfs6",
                    "diskType": "thick"
               }
        }
    ]
```

and use the same method for jInput["vm"][k][1]["devices"].keys()