# How to get OrderedDict values out of odict_iterator?

Tags: python

I am using the tsplib95 to parse .tsp files. I want to get a list of nodes
out of the Problem class from tsplib95. I checked the documentation, the
get_nodes() method returns an iter() over OrderedDict of nodes.

How do I access the values of the OrderedDict using the iterator?
I can only ever iterate over the key values using the iterator.

The OrderedDict looks like this:
 
OrderedDict([(1, (20833.3333, 17100.0)), ..., (29, (27462.5, 12992.2222))])

I tried getting the coordinates value in a for loop and using the **next**() method.

```
            tsp_instance = tsplib95.load_problem(file.value)
            iterator = tsp_instance.get_nodes()

            print(next(iterator))
            print(iterator.__next__())

            for i in iterator:
                print(i)
```

But all of these only access the keys in the OrderedDict
I do not know how to get the values of the coordinates when I do not have the original OrderedDict.

Comment: Did you try ```for key, value in iterator.items():```?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating Over Dictionary Key Values Corresponding to List in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409078/iterating-over-dictionary-key-values-corresponding-to-list-in-python)

Comment: @accdias yes, I have tried that already. I get AttributeError: 'odict_iterator' object has no attribute 'items'.

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you using `get_nodes` for this, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a different iterator.  The default iterator does not know the values, only the keys.
For example

```
>>> od = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
>>> iterator = iter(od.items())
>>> print(list(iterator))
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

In Python 2, you can also do `iterator = od.iteritems()`

Answer (score 0):

`get_nodes()` is not the tool you should be using for this. `get_nodes()` is only intended to return an iterator over nodes; the fact that this iterator is sometimes an iterator over an OrderedDict is an implementation detail, and it will not always be an OrderedDict iterator.

If you want to access the node coordinates of a problem instance that has node coordinates, you should use [`get_graph()`](https://tsplib95.readthedocs.io/modules.html#tsplib95.models.Problem.get_graph) and inspect the NetworkX [node attributes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#node-attributes); the coordinates for a node will be under the `'coord'` node attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this! The main reason I tried using the get_nodes() is that I noticed that the NetworkX plot kept being different after running the script multiple times and wanted to see what was going on.

Now that I checked the node attributes the data in the network are indeed the same as in the .tsp file. I will have a closer look at the NetworkX library and figure out what is going on.